# How to make Tor Browser reload a page every minute automatically, and why don't all browsers have this?

Tags: browser, web, tor, vivaldi

Vivaldi has a feature that lets you right-click a tab and select "Periodic reload" and a number of minutes to auto-reload it. This is crucial for idiotic websites which automatically kick you out for inactivity and have very annoying means of logging in. (Extreme CAPTCHAs, hoop-jumping, dongles, etc.)

But when using .onion sites, I must use Tor Browser for sufficient security. And that browser has no such feature that I can see.

How is this possible? Why doesn't every browser since the dawn of time have this feature? Is it hidden somewhere in Tor Browser?

Comment: Because not every user since the dawn of times wants their page reloaded. Imagine if you're completing an online form for a tax bill, and the page reloads? You'd lose all of your work. Chrome has an extension called Super Easy Auto Refresh which I use for pages I want refreshing, but in my 20+ years of IT, you're the first person I've heard of who expects a browser to have built-in automatic page refreshing.

Comment: @spikey_richie What?! Nobody said that it would do this *by default*, and you must be crazy if you assume that anyway. It's something you enable.

Comment: Anyway, back to your question. Why not raise a feature request with the Tor development team? https://trac.torproject.org/ There's also a Tor stack sister site here https://tor.stackexchange.com/ where you could ask a more specific question about Tor.

Comment: Zukosky, welcome to SU. Please tone down your question/comment just a bit, despite the strawman argument - I agree with your sentiment, but you don't need to go calling people crazy for not having the same use case as you do. Vivaldi is what Opera used to be - a browser for power users, with extreme configurability as one of the key features. Tor clearly has a different primary purpose. As spikey said, you can put in a request to have that feature added.